# Struct Inheritance Constructor Functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I have this `struct BTNode` and I would like to create a sub `struct SubBTNode` that inherits from `BTNode`. My problem is in the constructor function of `SubBTNode`. I want `SubBTNode` to inherit all of the same properties as `BTNode`, but with some additional data fields, `postOrderX`, `preOrderX`, `inOrderX`

BTNode

```
struct BTNode {
    BTNode* parent;
    BTNode* left;
    BTNode* right;
    int x;

    BTNode(int x, BTNode* parent = NULL, BTNode* left = NULL, BTNode* right = NULL): x(x), parent(parent), left(left), right(right) {}
};
```

SubBTNode

```
struct SubBTNode : BTNode {
    int preOrderX;
    int inOrderX;
    int postOrderX;

    SubBTNode(int x) : 
                preOrderX(x), inOrderX(x), postOrderX(x) {}
};
```

`error: no matching function for call to 'BTNode::BTNode()'
                 preOrderX(x), inOrderX(x), postOrderX(x) {}`

Comment: You need to call the `BTNode` constructor with all of the proper parameters since you have no default constructor. `SubBTNode(int x) : BTNode(x)...`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see any questions on this topic. If you want to put an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: The code isn't **C**, please stop spamming irrelevant tags.